# Error in doing npm install or npm install -g?

Tags: node.js

Error in doing npm install or npm install -g Nodejs "Permission Denied" ?

how to resolve this error?

i am doing

```
npm install

npm install -g
```

Comment: `sudo npm install -g `

Comment: @jasmine which OS you are using. Windows or Mac or some other.

Answer (score 0):

sudo npm install -g will do for global installation